# Proofs utilizing the Well-Ordering Property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

This question comes directly from as an example in Chapter 5.2 of Rosen's *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications* textbook on page 341.

#### Example

Use the well-ordering property to prove the division algorithm. Recall that the division algorithm states that if $a$ is an integer and $d$ is a positive integer, then there are unique integers $q$ and $r$ with $0 \leq r < d$ and $a = dq + r$.

#### Solution

Let $S$ be the set of nonnegative integers of the form $a − dq$, where $q$ is an integer. This set is nonempty because $−dq$ can be made as large as desired (taking q to be a negative integer with large absolute value). By the well-ordering property, $S$ has a least element $r = a − dq_\text{0}$.

The integer $r$ is nonnegative. It is also the case that $r < d$. If it were not, then there would be a smaller nonnegative element in $S$, namely, $a − d(q0 + 1)$. To see this, suppose that $r ≥ d$. Because $a=dq_\text{0}+r$, it follows that $a−d(q_\text{0}+1)=(a−dq_\text{0})−d=r−d \geq 0$. Consequently, there are integers $q$ and $r$ with $0 \leq r < d$.

#### My Questions

1. Why we are considering a set $S$ of remainders $r$? How does that relate to proving the correctness of the division algorithm?
2. What is a better explanation of why $r < d$?
3. What is a set of actual numbers that I can use to test this proof on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. He's using the set of remainders to prove it in full generality. Try to verifiy the proof *locally*, take some integers and divide them by any other number, see what happens if $d=r$ and $d<r$, just as I wrote below. This will give you a *local* intuition about the proof. Now there is one question (a very important one): How does one generalize this result? How do you know that for **any** natural number $x$ divided by **any** other natural number gives you a unique remainder? For this, the author is using some important properties of the set of natural numbers.
2. Suppose the remainder could be equal to $d$, then you could do the following: $dq+r=d(q+1)+0$. For example: $6=2\cdot 2+2=6=2\cdot 3+0$ . (That is, if $r=d$, you could take this $r$ and then *put* it into the product $dq$ and then the reminder would equal $0$). Now try to do the same thing for a remainder bigger than $d$ and see what happens. (Remember: Try some examples first, and then try to prove it).
3. Well, you can test on pretty much any number. Take $7$, divide by $3$, it'll give you $7=2\cdot 3+1$, now try divide it by $4$. Notices that *divide* means that you need to do integer division: A division that yields exactly $dq+r$. On the case above, $7=\stackrel{d}{3} \cdot \stackrel{q}{2}+\stackrel{r}{1}$.

Comment: Thanks Voyska, proving it _locally_ definitely helps when proving it in full generality. Thanks for your speedy response!

Comment: @abmantha Yes. Seeing it locally really gives you the intuition, you always need examples and intuition, and then you can try to formalize it.

Answer (score 2):

$1:$ We consider the set of remainders because the goal of the proof is to show that there is a unique smallest remainder. If we weren't considering a *set* of remainders, then we would not be able to use the well-ordering principle to state that there is a smallest remainder.

$2:$ Suppose $r \geq d$. Then subtract $d$ from $r$ and increment $q$ to obtain a smaller value of $r$, while preserving equality. Repeating this process guarantees that $r < d$.
$$a = dq + r = dq + r -d + d$$
$$dq + r -d + d = dq + d + (r-d) = d(q+1) + (r-d)$$
As you can see, the final equality is in the appropriate form for the division algorithm, but with the smaller remainder $(r-d)$. If $r \geq d$, then clearly $r-d \geq 0$ (subtract $d$ from both sides).

$3:$ Any pair of integers. Repeatedly subtract the divisor from $a$ to get different remainders (most larger than $d$). These remainders form $S$, and you just proved that $S$ has a minimum value, which gives your solution. The number of subtractions performed is $q$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really clarifies my understanding of what we're actually trying to prove. Thank you for answer so quickly.

Comment: for $2$ i think you mean if $r\ge d$

Comment: @miniparser Thank you, I did mean that.